# How can I solve a set of non-linear equations?

Tags: equation-solving

I was wondering whether someone can give me an idea on how I can solve a set of non-linear equations with an unknown exponent

This is what I have:

- Known values: N, R
- Unknown values: λ, α, J
- Equations

  ```
  J = N1 + a*R1^λ  
  J = N2 + a*R2^λ
  J = N3 + a*R3^λ
  ```

The α, J, λ should be approximately the same in every equation

Additional info

The only thing I know according to the author of the paper is that "... by solving the three unknowns J, a, λ with a least-square solution scheme"

I know about least-squares, but not how to apply it when the exponent is unknown along with sum of `N`.

Comment: welcome here, may be you shall look at other questions on how you shall post your question.

Comment: Hi! To add to Blackbird's comment, aside from the formatting bar at the top of the edit box, there is an [editing help page](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) to help with formatting code.  Also, questions normally include a "minimal working example" of what you've tried, which is code folks can copy and paste to reproduce your problem.  It should be syntactically correct (but not necessarily a correct program).

Comment: Hi there and thanks for the reply
it is quite obvious that I am new here and therefore I have no idea on how a question suppose to look like...
So, a big thanks to Blackbird for the tip!!!

I am afraid I don't have any code as for now I am trying to find a method or a theory that can support my problem.

I am not looking for a direct answer but for an approach.

The only thing I know according to the Author of the paper is that...
"By solving the three unknowns J2, a, l with a least-
square solution scheme"

I know about least-square but no when the exponent is unknown along with sum. of "N"

Comment: You have 3 eqns, 3 unknowns so least squares should not be needed. Subtract n_i, i=1..3 from the respective equations. Then take logs. You now havea system that is linear in log(j-n_i), log(a), and lambda. Solve it and exponentiate where needed to solve for j and a.

Answer (score 2):

You can't solve this as it stands. You have one equation with 2 unknowns.

If you add `eq1` to `eq2` and multiply `eq3` by `2` and take the difference, you get one equation with only `a` and `lambda` in it.

```
Clear[j, \[Lambda], a, n1, n2, n3, r1, r2, r3];

eq1 = j == n1 + a*r1^\[Lambda];
eq2 = j == n2 + a*r2^\[Lambda];
eq3 = j == n3 + a*r3^\[Lambda];
eq4 = Inner[Plus, eq1, eq2, Equal]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
eq5 = Map[2 # &, eq3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
eq6 = Inner[Subtract, eq4, eq5, Equal]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
data = {n1 -> 1, n2 -> 2, n3 -> 3, r1 -> 4, r2 -> 5, r3 -> 6};
Expand[eq6 /. data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You can get another independent equation from adding `eq1` to `eq3` and multiplying `eq2` by 2 and taking the difference, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The equations are non-linear, and won't have any analytic solution in general. Since there are as many equations as unknowns, `FindRoot` may be used to obtain a numeric solution. However, since a "least-square" solution scheme is proposed, and each (n[i],r[i]) satisfy the same equation

```
n[i_]=J-a*r[i]^λ;
```

we can use `FindFit`, which [finds a least-squares fit by default](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFit.html).

To use either `FindRoot` or `FindFit`, we need numeric data, e.g.

```
n0 = {1,2,3};
r0 = {4,5,6};
{J0, a0, λ0} = {J, a, λ} /. FindFit[Transpose[{r0, n0}], n[i], {J, a, λ}, r[i]]
```

We can check `FindRoot` returns the same solution by

```
r[i_]:=r0[[i]]
FindRoot[Table[n[i]==n0[[i]],{i,3}],{{J,J0},{a,a0},{λ,λ0}}]
```

Comment: I don't necessarily consider "(`FindFit`) ... doesn't require an initial guess" an advantage; you can use `EvaluationMonitor` to show that `FindFit[]` always uses a vector of all 1's as the initial guess, which may or may not be appropriate to the system at hand.

Comment: I stand corrected then.. Is there any way to change this guess?

Comment: Certainly; as noted in the docs, you can supply seeds to `FindFit[]` as well, by providing a list of pairs of the parameter and its corresponding seed. In fact, quite a number of questions in here have answers where part of the advice goes like "you need to give `FindFit[]` better starting values".

Comment: Good to know. Thanks for pointing this out. Have edited out the offending claim.